# How to check/query active rdp connections to an ec2 machine?

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, remote-access, rdp, terminal-services

I have a couple of ec2 machines and need to inquire about any RDP sessions (connections) to those machines. I have tried various methods but I get access denied or 'RPC server is unavailable' messages. Although port 3389 is opened.

Here is the report on the methods I have tried:

1. RDP - works.
2. Ping - unable to ping.
3. Terminal Services - says 'Server not found'.
4. Query session - says 'RPC server is unavailable'.
5. Get-TSSession (Terminal Services module in power shell) - says 'RPC server is unavailable'.

I believe I had a problem either understanding the terminal services correct or the ec2 instance. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're on EC2, so you have security groups to contend with as well as the local firewalls on the instances.

For remote management of those windows machines, you are going to want to ensure your security group settings allow inbound access to TCP 139, TCP 445, UDP 137, UDP 138, and that the local firewalls on those machines allow inbound as well.

DO NOT open those ports to the world--only allow access from well-known static IP addresses, or use VPC.

Comment: Old post of mine and although it was my own mistake like I mentioned in my answer. But I have up voted your answer being in the right direction. Thanks buddy.